# VC++ 6.0 project error "more than one operator "+=" matches these operands"

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6

I'm currently working on a project developed on VC++ 6.0.

Rapidly the project consist to upgrade the project for the newer version of windows.

The source file that is posing the problem is used to manage the display of some information with the HTTP protocol.

Here is the part with errors :

```
DWORD CChronoSocket::reply_http(DWORD i, const char * sin){
const unsigned char * in = (const unsigned char *) sin;
CString data = "";
while (*in)
    if (*in<128) 
        data += *in++;
    else 
        data += 0xc2+(*in>0xbf), //more than one operator "+=" matches these operands
        data += (*in++&0x3f)+0x80; //more than one operator "+=" matches these operands


CString header;

DWORD length = strlen(data);

header  = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
header += "Server: ChronoMaster Server\r\n";
header += "Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:59:59 GMT\r\n";
header += "Pragma: no-cache\r\n";
header += "Content-type: text/json; \r\n";
char buff2[32];
sprintf(buff2, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", length);
header += buff2;
header += "\r\n";
::send(struct_socket[i].sock, header, header.GetLength(), 0 );

::send(struct_socket[i].sock, data, length, 0 );

return 0;}
```

I think I understand it's a problem with the format in the two sides of the operator but where I try to convert in other formats my program is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help

And sorry for my bad English ^^'

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 and visual-c++6 are different products. The latter was released in 1998.

Comment: A question -- why did you only go to Visual Studio 2010?  In this day and age, the earliest version of VC++ to use is Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3.  And that is even stretching it.  Starting off with 2010 is not a good idea IMO, since it is not a C++ 11 compliant compiler.

Comment: That looks like a really simplistic UTF-8 encoder.  You might want to use OS-provided functions that do this for you... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100603-00/?p=13823

Comment: I use VS2010 because I saw that it was the best version to go from old versions (2005,2008 ...) to new ones (2017,2019).
I will definitely give VS2015 a try but it doesn't change my problem.

Comment: The RHS of `data += 0xc2+(*in>0xbf),` will result in an `int` not a `char` Try static casting to char.  ps is the `,` at the end a typo?

Comment: Thank you Richard it's working now you save me ^^'. Have a nice day. (For th `,` it's not a typo.)

Comment: The `,` at the end is very bad practice.  Wrap the else body in `{` ... `}` and change the `,` to `;`, and punch the person who did that as hard as you can.